# reloading the fetched chats area

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have created a chatting system using php+ajax +mysql which is working fine in fetching and inserting but failed to reload the new chats. for example: user 'x' is chatting with user 'y' so when user x sends a message to y only the x's message area shows the newly sent message in real time but not in y's side.the same thing happens for y's side.
my jquery code is:

```
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
  $(document).on('click', '.first_name', function(){  
       var id=$(this).data("id1");  
       fetch_chat();
              function fetch_chat()  
                {  
                    $.ajax({  
                    url:"fetch_chat.php",  
                    method:"POST",  
                    data:{id:id},  
                    dataType:"text",  
                    success:function(data){  
                    $('#messages').html(data);  
                    $("div.area").show();
                    }     

                  });  
                }  


                $("#sub").off("click").on("click", function() {
                var text= $("#text").val();
                $.post('insert_chat.php',{id:id,msg:text},function(data){
                $("#messages").append(data);
                $("#text").val('');
                 });
            });

  });  
 });  
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fisrt:** Put the fetch_chat function out of `onclick` even out of `document.ready` block. You are defining the fetch function on click!

**Second:** The person Y must fetch the chat content periodical (e.g. `javascript setInterval`) to receive responses from server every 1 seconds (for example) .

However if you want to fetch data as soon as possible, there is hack method that the Y sends a single request to the server and waits until the server respond him. In this method instead of repeating task in user browser, you have to create a repeating task in server side. The server task send periodical request to database and when new data fetched, pushes it to the queued request of person Y. as soon as the Y receives the respond, sends a new request to server and waits again to receive respond. In this method, network timeout and server timeout must be handled or you can also define an additional interval (in long periods) from Y side to overcome the network timeout.

a very simpel simulation of serverside response:

request from Y browser:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'serverside-fetch.php',
   success: function(data){
       $("#messages").append(data);
   }
})
```

respond from server **serverside-fetch.php**:

```
var data="";
while (data=="") {
   //data= fetch recent unread rows from chat database
}
echo data;
```

and this is the corrected code in X side:

```
  $(document).on('click', '.first_name', function(){  
       var id=$(this).data("id1");  
       fetch_chat();

  });

   $("#sub").off("click").on("click", function() {
      var text= $("#text").val();
      $.post('insert_chat.php',{id:id,msg:text},function(data){
      $("#messages").append(data);
      $("#text").val('');
      });
   });

   function fetch_chat()  
    {  
        $.ajax({  
        url:"fetch_chat.php",  
        method:"POST",  
        data:{id:id},  
        dataType:"text",  
        success:function(data){  
          $('#messages').html(data);  
          $("div.area").show();
          }     
         });  
     }
```

Comment: I have cleaned the answer to be more clear for X-side , Y-side and Server-side codes.